# Copies link and closes box with one keyboard shortcut

Tags: feature-request, keyboard-shortcuts

I have enabled keyboard shortcuts for this site.

Pressing <kbd>L</kbd> on a question or answer will display a box with a link, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> will have the link copied, but then I'll have to manually close the box.  It can be more convenient to use <kbd>Enter</kbd> instead of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, if the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key

1. Copies the link, then
2. Closes the box.

On a regular <kbd>qwerty</kbd> keyboard, <kbd>L</kbd> then <kbd>enter</kbd> are close enough to be hit by a single hand.

I request this feature to be added.

Answer (score 2):

> but then I'll have to manually close the box

Or you can press <kbd>Esc</kbd> to close the box.

I'm sure there are scenarios where copying the link *shouldn't* close the popup. It's not exactly something a user would expect:

> [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) *"I copied the link, but the box closed?!"*

Comment: Oh, that exists? Well, it's not as convenient, but good to know. Note that I did not propose Ctrl+C to close the box.